# How To Get Last Data with JPA Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jpa

I have a table in mysql database (warehouse transaction). It has columns itemid, warehouseid, date, movement (in out qty), and balance.

Example:

```
Id | Date             | ItemId | WarehouseId | Movement | Balance
1  | 01-01-2020 01:00 | 1      | 1           |      100 |    100
2  | 01-01-2020 02:00 | 1      | 1           |      -10 |     90
3  | 01-01-2020 03:00 | 3      | 1           |       50 |     50
4  | 01-01-2020 03:00 | 1      | 1           |       -5 |     85
5  | 02-01-2020 01:00 | 1      | 1           |       -5 |     80
6  | 02-01-2020 02:00 | 1      | 1           |      -10 |     70
7  | 02-01-2020 03:00 | 2      | 1           |      200 |    200
8  | 04-01-2020 01:00 | 1      | 1           |      -20 |     50
9  | 04-01-2020 02:00 | 2      | 1           |      -20 |    180
```

So, if I want to know the balance's items in warehouse 1 on 02-01-2020, it should give me result:

```
3  | 01-01-2020 03:00 | 3      | 1           |       50 |     50
6  | 02-01-2020 02:00 | 1      | 1           |      -10 |     70
7  | 02-01-2020 03:00 | 2      | 1           |      200 |    200
```

Id 3, 6 and 7 are the last record for ItemId 1, ItemId 2 and ItemId 3.

Is it possible to get that result in one JPA query? If yes, can someone help me with the query? or may be mysql query?

My target, I want to run a single query to avoid multiple query.

I can get it in a single query for every item and warehouse. It's ok, when there are 10 items. But when there are 100 or more items, it will run more than 100x query.

Thank you.

Comment: Why `Balance=70` for `ItemId=1` is taken and `Balance=80` is skipped? None sorting (which uses only shown data) allows to find that this recod is the last one. Maybe some autoincremented field exists? or `Date` field is datetime in practice?

Comment: Either have timstamps instead of dates, or transaction id. Or both!

Comment: To write a JPA query we'd need to see the entities which you haven't added. Additionally, as noted in a previous comment there is n o way to actually identify the last record from the information given. needs more focus.

Comment: I added the table with Id and time stamp on transaction date. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Do you need the last data or the last data on a partícular date that may not be the last date?

Comment: I need the last data on a particular date that may not be the last date. If there is itemId 3 and it's last transaction on 01-01-2020 02:00, it should be also show up on the query result. I will edit the example

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the query required can be written in JPQL. But in JPA you always have the option of executing a native query.

The SQL to retrieve the results you need would be something like this:

```
select * from TRANSACTION_TABLE T1 
where T1.warehouseid = ?1 
and T1.date = (
    select max(date) from TRANSACTION_TABLE T2 
    where T2.date < ?2 
    and T2.itemid = T1.itemid
    and T2.warehouseid = T1.warehouseid
)
```

(The second parameter would be the date you want plus one day).

Comment: Hi, did you try it?